# Algorithm to turn JavaScript object into efficient query string/urls

Tags: javascript, typescript, serialization, query-string

Context: I have been building an application that creates and uses magnet links. I've been trying to find an efficient way to transfer a javascript object in the Querystring so that On the other side I can deserialize it into an object keeping the same types. with efficient i mean using as little characters as possible/transferring as much data as possible. I've found my application has a max of +-1500 characters in url.

At first I used original Querystring npm packages but these can change types on deserialize and also very inefficient on deeper objects.

eg:

```
var input = { age: 12, name:'piet'};
var qs = querystring.encode(input); // ?age=12&name=piet
var output querystring.decode(qs); // {age: '12', name: 'piet'
```

Then I've tried using json stringifying with and without base64 for Querystrings. But this left me most of the time with much bigger strings for simple objects.

```
var input = { age: 12, name:'piet'};
var qs = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(input)); // "%7B%22age%22%3A12%2C%22name%22%3A%22piet%22%7D"
```

But this leaves me with rediculous long querystring because half of the characters get encoded and become 3x as long which almost doubles the length.

base64 encoding in this case is a much better solution:

```
var input = { age: 12, name:'piet'};
var qs = btoa(JSON.stringify(input)); // eyJhZ2UiOjEyLCJuYW1lIjoicGlldCJ9
```

I've been trying to Google for an efficient algorithm it but haven't really found a good solution. I've been looking into msgPack binary serialisation by then I would also have to base64 which probably ends with a longer string.

Is there a known more efficient algorithm for object to Querystring serialisation with static types? or would i have to create my own?

I've been thinking on on a simple query string algorithm that works as follows:

- Query string order is imporotant, for next point:
- Keys starts with . shows depth: ?obj&.property="test" = { obj : {property: "test" }}
- First character in string defines its type: b=boolean, s=string,n=number, (etc if needed)

This would lead to much more efficient query string i think. but am i not building something that has already been made before?

Comment: why don't you just `JSON.stringify` and stick that in as some attr of the query string? All escped?

Comment: You said your application creates and uses magnet links. Isn't a magnet link just a [hashed pointer to a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#Normal_(as))? That sounds like just a regular string, as opposed to a Javascript object. Also could you clarify that level of depth the objects are that you're trying to serialise? Or do you not know ahead of time how deep they might be?

Answer (score 0):

Surely sticking the stringified object into a single URI value should work?

```
var test = { string: 'string', integer: 8, intarray: [1,2,3] };

encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(test))
// "%7B%22string%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22integer%22%3A8%2C%22intarray%22%3A%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%7D"

JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22string%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22integer%22%3A8%2C%22intarray%22%3A%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%7D")
// {string: "string", integer: 8, intarray: [1, 2, 3]}
```

The object parsed at the end has the same types as the object inputted at the start.

Just stick your object into a single key:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/query?key=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Right? And on the server you just parse that single value into an object.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear. this ofc i already tried but it leaves you with this massive query string where al json characters are encoded into 3 characters (eg: %22 = 3 chars)